# What's with this Chuck Yeager hat thingy>

Tags: bug

What's with this Chuck Yeager hat?

How did I get it?  What is it good for?

If I plug it into the mains what colour smoke will I get?

When I wear it it covers my eyes and I can't see out proper like -
Can I get a smaller version - or an (even) larger head?

Comment: Apparently nobody shares details about secret hats other than vague hints (they probably don't know themselves exactly how they got it). My opinion is: Enjoy the hat if you like it and don't tire yourself with trying to solve riddles.

Comment: Maybe it would work if you used a better portrait.  Geesh, you're into photography and that's the best you can come up with!?  Too often people seem to forget that the size of portraits displayed here are *tiny*, so fill the frame as best you can else we can't see much of anything.

Comment: @OlinLathrop The sheriff has a remarkably good setup for taking identification photos, and he'll even do it for free!

Comment: @OlinLathrop "Better" is in the spacetimemindset of the beholder. I'm very happy with that image and filling the frame has no more relevance to it than rule of thirds or other march-in-step rules (that I know you also have little time for) demand. It's an 'experimental' photo from a series of playings which I intend to get back to "soon". As may be seen from [**"A somewhat larger version"**](https://scontent-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/1074430_511597808913719_2115049879_o.jpg) the apparent (and actual :-) ) mess is a photo that 'could not have been taken by a camera' but is in fact ...

Comment: ... an "out of camera" image. The "method" produces "results" that are only somewhat controllable and I'm working on learning how to use it well enough to produce images which are quirky & impossible but also potentially interesting and useful. So far 'quirky' predominates :-). | My "Chuck Yeager hat" question was intended to be light hearted (as I imagine you realise) in the spirit of the hat 'event'. And yes, I know how to get the hat to fit my head image just dandy- I may get it to do so when all the hats are put away.

Comment: I guess we think of the portrait here differently.  I view most of the the profile, photo included, as being for everyone else.  It's a courtesy to let others see your face when you are talking to them.  Same goes for the location in your profile.  It's context other people want to have when talking to you.  In my view, this isn't the place for quirky, although lots of others clearly disagree.

Comment: @OlinLathrop We agree and disagree simultaneously :-) - I don't know that the profile image on posts are large enough, even when solidly frame filled with one's facial image, to do much of a job of letting people 'see one's face'. If a person viewing my posts could NOT identify me from that image I'd be happier than not. If they care enough to look at my profile page the image is large enough to serve what requirements courtesy may demand. Want they more, I've added a link at the end, AND the given email address in the profile works, the city and country are real and the website referenced ...

Comment: ... is actually a photo site that should slake most curiosity re me and related matters - although not as directly as emailing me or using Google.  Quirky I may be, as occasions leads, but I'm happy that the SE are well enough served wrt available information about me.

Comment: I see you came up with your own solution to a well-fitting Chuck Yaeger helmet.

Comment: @OlinLathrop - You noticed :-). 'Well fitting' for a very limited range of values of 'well'. Lifetime of image expected to be "short" :-)

Comment: @RussellMcMahon, and now you're the only one with a hat ;-)

Comment: @PeterJ - Aye. It will vanish when I get around to finding another "suitable" picture :-). Needs to fill the frame, apparently :-).

Answer (score 3):

Oh dear... *you* weren't supposed to get that hat.

Unfortunately, in a bit of oversight, mods weren't given the ability to delete hats, so I'm afraid you'll have to live with it. (Or click the "I hate hats" link).

All hats are "One Size Fits All". If you're unhappy with the fit, then I'm afraid you'll have to trim your head for comfort.

And *do* be careful with the sound barrier - we only get one per site and the evil overlords don't like it when we break stuff.

Comment: Are you serious about me not being meant to get the hat? I mind not (of course) as it's all in fun etc but I'd be interested in knowing how I did get it if unintended. I had (of course) looked at comments re hats elsewhere before I asked this question - it just seemed a fun thing to ask and in the spirit of the occasion. I gained the impression that Chuck Yeager was related to postings on Meta so it seemed strange that I had it.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I'm not being serious. The Chuck Yeager hat is only awarded on the main site, but the unicorn hat is awarded for meta participation

Comment: +1 for telling him he needs to trim his head to fit the hat.

Comment: Congrats on the secret hat @RussellMcMahon! They wont even tell you how you earned it.

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search shows two threads elsewhere on SO:

- [I have a Secret Hat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/211707/i-have-a-secret-hat)
- [How Do I Get the Winterbash 2013 Secret Hats?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/212799/how-do-i-get-the-winterbash-2013-secret-hats)

As they are secret hats I didn't manage to find an exact answer anywhere, but it was pretty obvious when I found those two threads why I'd got the hat.

And a clue: this answer would possibly qualify.